# Scanner return null

Tags: android, zxing, nativescript

Im using a *3rd party library* (`Zxing`) for **bar code scanner** . The result of scannig is `null`. After the scan I try adding the result into a `label` but the result is `null`.

Here is my code :

```
if (requestCode === SCANNER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode === android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK) {
  // Handle successful scan
  var contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
  var format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
  // var scanned = page.getViewById("scanned");
  //scanned.url = "";
  pageData.set("message", contents);
  page.bindingContext = pageData;
}
```

Comment: My (working) code looks the same, so I guess your problem is caused by another part of your code. If you want easy Zxing integration, you could use the android-integration classes: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/android-integration

Comment: @hrskrss its about this line of code :  " var contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");" . Cause when i enter a static value to contents it is working